# Mochahost GWT rpc and Servlet not working

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

While deploying my app to mochahost, I met the problem between `servlet` and `GWT-RPC` communicate. The error shows:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /403.shtml
type Status report
message /403.shtml
description The requested resource (/403.shtml) is not available.
```

`.war` file works perfectly on my workstation, but not working on `mochahost`.

Any ideas to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mochahost have a very good support, try livechatting with their tech department, you will probably have the thing solved.

That's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you update live site URL. For instance, generally, on local system you access web app as `http://localhost:8080/myapp` but, on server it changes to http://[www.]myapp.com. Again, this is just an instance. The point is, the live site must reflect correct URL from code (servlet/JSP/action/etc...) and configuration properties, if any.
2. Comment 'DirectoryIndex' property in .htaccess file if you do not have any index file.
3. Comment 'RewriteCond' property in .htaccess file if you do not have any rewrite requirement.
4. For sure, one of the reason - if client does not accept cookies and servlet does not encode URL.